# How to make edittext in android both multi line and and initcap

Tags: android, android-edittext

I found out that `android:inputType` and adding `"textMultiLine"` and `"textCapSentences"` makes the input text multiline and init cap respectively, but how can we collaborate both to one edit text?
because error is shown when i put two `android:inputType` in a single edittext.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />  // cannot add this here
```

i tried as per the answer but
the multiline is working but init cap is not working in both this edittext and the ones written as

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

:-(

Comment: i mean it is working in mobile, but in emulator i think its using keyboard input type, if capslock is turned in its in caps, if off, its small letter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use like this..

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

In your code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" 
    android:ems="10"/>
```

Comment: the multiline is working but init cap is not working in both this edittext and the ones written as `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` :-(

Comment: i mean it is working in mobile, but in emulator i think its using keyboard input type, if capslock is turned in its in caps, if off, its small letter

Answer (score 0):

inputType attribute (textCapSentence) is IME dependent.

You can achieve your requirement by adding below line:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

Still in some keyboards, it will not work. I have also used this and it is working in almost all the keyboards(Nexus, Samsung, HTC) but not in Motorola.

Comment: @Mukund: in which device, you are testing it?